# rails 3.2.9 jquery_ujs not working with link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've have at least the following links that don't work

```
= link_to 'Delete', admin_picture_comment_path(comment.picture_id,comment.id), :class => 'delete', :remote => true ,:method => :delete

= link_to 'Disable', set_shown_admin_picture_path(picture), :class => 'delete', :method => :put, :remote => true

= link_to 'show', set_show_admin_picture_path(picture), :class => 'delete', :method => :put, :remote => true

= link_to 'delete', admin_picture_path(picture), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :class => 'delete', :method => :delete, :remote => true
```

The HTML that is being created looks correct

```
<a href="/admin/pictures/27/comments/25" class="delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

<a href="/admin/pictures/27/set_shown" class="delete" data-method="put" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Disable</a>
```

In all cases I get back something that like

No route matches **[GET]** "/admin/pictures/27/comments/23"

I assume this is because the jquery_ujs is not loading correctly, however I have no idea why it's not loading as it shows up in the html header

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.fileupload.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.fileupload-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.lightbox.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

#### Routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  #...
  resources :pictures do # admin/pictures
    member do
      put 'set_show'     
      put 'set_shown'
    end
    resources :comments, :only => [:destroy]
  end
end
```

#### application.html.haml

```
%html
  %head
    %title title
    = stylesheet_link_tag :application
    = javascript_include_tag :application
    = csrf_meta_tag
```

#### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.fileupload
//= require jquery.fileupload-ui
//= require jquery.lightbox

$(function(){

  $('.admin_picture a.delete').live('ajax:success',function(){
    $(this).closest('.admin_picture').fadeOut();
  });

  $('tr .ajax_delete').live('ajax:success', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
  });

  $('.comment a.delete').live('ajax:success',function(){
    $(this).closest('.comment').slideUp();
  });

  //...

});
```

#### gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'thin'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml-rails'   
#...
```

I ran into this error while upgrading from a rails 3.0 application that was using unobtrusive jquery, what could I possibly be missing that would cause this.

Comment: Do you see an error in your javascript console (in the browser developer tools)? Because if you have some javascript error on your page, your javascript could just stop working.

Comment: No javascript errors that I can see.

Comment: Turns out it was a javascript error. It wasn't showing up as a javascript error because under settings >> console , "Perserve log upon navigation" was unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

specifically, my jquery_ujs file was old and still "living" in my assets/javascript directory.  It still had .live methods which are deprecated.  Delete the file!!
Keep the gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'  # REF: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs
Keep the     //= require jquery and //= require jquery_ujs and //= require_tree .
In your application.js file
Make sure you update the gem and bundle install to get the latest gem.
If a javascript error is thrown as was the "sneaky" case for me, the rest of link_to js will not work.

Comment: I would not recommend the "Delete the Gemfile.lock", you can just call `bundle update jquery-rails` to update the lock file